# What is landscape and autopilot?

Tags: openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Currently I am searching for an alternative for VMware ESXI. I came across Openstack. Now I searching and searching, but I just can't figure out what landscape and autopilot is? It is for managing or something, but what does it do and how do they interact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Landscape and its [Autopilot](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/openstack/autopilot) component can install OpenStack for you, provided you meed the hardware requirements.

OpenStack is a whole new ballgame when compared to VMware. ESXi is not a cloud, it's just a rack of (virtual) machines.